# Gazebo throwing error in opening model created in it

Tags: ros, gazebo

I created my world with gazebo9 and saved it.

```
world$ tree
.
└── myworld
    ├── model.config
    └── model.sd
```

Now when I start it with

```
$ gazebo myworld
```

I get

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Why am I getting a memory error when all this ran fine. Starting Gazebo on its own works.

I am using:
Ubuntu 18.04
gazebo9

[Question 1](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/13553/unable-to-run-gazebo-from-the-terminal/) and [Question 2](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/18805/problem-with-gazebo-stdbad_alloc/) don't have solutions.

I have restarted my virtual machine and still get the same error. In some cases, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be confusing Gazebo worlds and models. A world is a single [SDF](http://sdformat.org/spec) file structured as below:

```
<sdf version="VERSION">
  <world name="NAME">
    <!-- Included models, links etc. -->
  </world>
</sdf>
```

For example, these are the contents of the sample `/usr/share/gazebo-9/worlds/willowgarage.world` world file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <world name="default">
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://willowgarage</uri>
    </include>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

In order to pre-load a world at startup time, you pass the path to the file as argument to Gazebo:

```
$ gazebo /usr/share/gazebo-9/worlds/willowgarage.world
```

The directory structure you described looks more like that of a [model](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_structure), which in addition to a SDF file also includes a configuration and (optionally) other resources such as meshes, materials etc. As far as I know there's no way to directly load a model at startup time, other than as an element included in a world file.

So to answer your question, the problem is probably that Gazebo is expecting its argument to point to an SDF file, but finds it to be a directory instead, and crashes as a result.